# HTML Form submission with javascript confirm delays on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-chrome, confirm

I realized that there's some delay on form submission with javascript confirmation on Google Chrome during my development.

So I tried test with small html page to make sure whether the delay is caused by my application. But it still happening in the test page.

I just don't want to confirm on form's onsubmit event as there will be more than one submission for different purposes.

So here's my test html.

```
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentTime = new Date()
    document.write(currentTime.getMilliseconds());
</script>
<form name="input" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure to submit?');" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I avoid that delay? Do I need to change anything from my end?

Please correct if that caused by my html which is not construct well form or missing something.

Thanks.

Comment: Chrome is taking some delay to submit the form if it displays any dialogs in the onclick method...

Comment: I don't understand this question at all.  Where is the delay?  How does your test file analyse this delay? Also, I would avoid using 'input' as a form name.

Comment: @Elangovan, So are you saying that it is a normal? or is it something has to be changed in application?

Comment: @graphicdivine, You can just noticed that by seeing Text above on button. It's supposed to be changed immediately after you clicked OK on confirm dialog. Make sure to test on Google Chrome.

Comment: But that number is just the number of milliseconds in the current date at the time of page load.  It has nothing to do with the button, or the submit.

Comment: @aunghn It is not problem with your code.. the delay is from chrome. It checks if the page displays too many dialogs whenever a dialog is displayed and provides a checkbox to the user to prevent further dialogs from the page. I am guessing the delay is due to this check, but I am not sure...

Comment: @Elangovan, Thanks for your info. So I may go with different way of approach.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code. The less significant one is that you're using `javascript:` in your `onclick` attibute, which is not needed. `on*` attributes are implicitly evaluated as JavaScript already - they're not like hyperlinks.

Secondly, and most importantly, that timer value you're showing on screen is *not* showing what you think it does.  It's just getting the current date and time, and extracting the millisecond component. That essentially gives you a random number between 0 and 999.  If that's what you're using to determine the submission delay, you are mistaken. Rest assured that the form will be submitted as soon as you press OK on the confirmation dialog, and any delay you experience is entirely due to page load time (assuming there are no page unload scripts).

Answer (score 0):

Oddly I was having a similar problem as you, but it was also appearing in FF as well... After reworking things I came up with:

```
<form name='doClear' action='index.php' method='post' >
    <input type='submit' value='Clear All' onclick='return confirm(\"Are you sure you want to clear all? This cannot be undone!\");' />
</form>";
```

Which works instantly for me. I am not sure where my issues were coming from before, but things are working fine now. Good luck.